# How to add content via ajax using the popover boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to view different sources and also looked into the forums posting similar question, but it didnt quite help me with the issue that im facing.
I have a text input filed to which I'm adding a popover to show similar a list of names in the database. The inout field checks for validation, to see if the name entered is unique, if not it displays similar names available in the database that could be re-used.
here is the popover snippet:

```
$("#account_name_create").popover({ 
                title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover', 
                content: function (process) {
                    this.accountCollection = new ipiadmin.collections.AccountCollection();
                    var newName = $("#new-account-form #account_name_create").val();
                    var userFilter = "accountName~'" + newName + "'";
                    this.accountCollection.fetch({
                    data: { "f": userFilter,
                        "sortby": null,
                        "type":"ipi",
                        "pageno":0,
                        "pagesize":2,
                        "reversesort" : true
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(model, response, options) {
                        var states = [];
                        map = {};
                        $.each(model.aDataSet, function (i, state) {
                            map[state.accountName] = state;
                            states.push(state.accountName);
                        }); 
                        process(states);  //gives an error saying 'undefined is not a function (says process is undefined)'
                    },
                    error: function(model, response, options) {
                    console.log('error');
                    }
                });

            },
        });
```

here is the html:

```
<input type="text" id="account_name_create" name="account_name" class="" size="40" />
```

I'm not sure how why it says 'process' as undefined. Also not sure if this would be the correct way of displaying the data in the popover.
Any ideas??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process` doesn't have scope in the success function, only in the content function. If you want to call the `process` function from within the success function, you could define it somewhere outside of the jQuery call.

Comment: like how? can you help me by showing from the above code?

Comment: The indentation threw me off. So, where is the `process` parameter defined, that you are passing into the `content` function?

Comment: sorry for the identation..im passing the process params in the content: function(){} so ideally its still in the scope of the success:function{}, i think

Comment: But where is the `process` function defined? I don't see any code for it? Is it defined elsewhere in your javascript file? In a different file? Where's the code for it?

Comment: the process function is defined in boostarp.js file: process: function () {
  550          var scrollTop = this.$scrollElement.scrollTop() + this.options.offset
  551            , scrollHeight = this.$scrollElement[0].scrollHeight || this.$body[0].scrollHeight
  ...
 2049      }

Comment: After looking at the source code for bootstrap, the `process` function is an internal function of [ScrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy), which requires the use of a nav bar, as ScrollSpy "automatically updates nav targets based on scroll position". I don't think that function is supposed to be used the way you're using it. Also, after [playing with it in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lJvqaYn9R9bhaCjTubKy), it looks like no parameters are passed into the content function. If you open up the dev tools and run it, it should stop at `debugger`, and you can inspect it.

Comment: Thats right, i did debugged it and thats when i found the process being undefined. I'm not sure how to pass params that will help me get the data to display depending on the test in typed in the input field